# Adding greyscale fx to a class using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, grayscale

I'm trying to use jQuery to add a greyscale fx to every image that has a class `greyscale`, but the below doesn't seem to work.  Has anyone got any ideas on why this may not be working?

```
    $(function(){

        var imgObj = $('.greyscale');       
       var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imgW = imgObj.width;
        var imgH = imgObj.height;
        canvas.width = imgW;
        canvas.height = imgH;

        canvasContext.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);
        var imgPixels = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, imgW, imgH);

        for(var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
            for(var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
                var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
                var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
                imgPixels.data[i] = avg; 
                imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg; 
                imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
            }
        }

        canvasContext.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
        return canvas.toDataURL();
 });
```

Comment: Note that getImageData wont work on if page not hosted on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're currently doing wrong is:

- Drawing a jQuery object and not a canvas
- Returning a data URL inside a ready handler, which seems to be meaningless

What you should do is:

- Iterate over all image elements, doing the following for each canvas:

  - Make a greyscale version
  - Set the image `href` to the data URL of the greyscale canvas

Like: http://jsfiddle.net/eGjak/140/.

```
$(window).load(function() { // wait for images to load also
    var imgObj = $('.greyscale');
    return imgObj.each(function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imgW = this.width;
        var imgH = this.height;
        canvas.width = imgW;
        canvas.height = imgH;

        canvasContext.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        var imgPixels = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, imgW, imgH);

        for(var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
            for(var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
                var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
                var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
                imgPixels.data[i] = avg; 
                imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg; 
                imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
            }
        }

        canvasContext.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
        console.log(canvas.toDataURL())
        this.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    });
});
```

Comment: What I have is an image with the class greyscale which i want to move to the canvas then convert the canvas to greyscale.

Comment: Please see http://www.chillwebdesigns.co.uk/test/gs/gs.htm why do you think the canvas is not being made the same as the images?

Comment: @Chill Web Designs: Could you try using `$(window).load` instead of the ready handler? The images have to load first, and the `ready` function (`$(function(){})`) does not wait for images but only the DOM.

Comment: Found out the issue, it gets the real image size rather than the size specified in the CSS.